# Copying data from table without primary key to a table with a pk

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, primary-key

I have two tables `foo` and `bar` in Postgres with the same structure except that `bar` is empty and has a primary key called `id`, while `foo` is populated and has a column called `id` with unique values (but it does not have a  primary key).

When I attempt to copy data from `foo` to `bar` using this command:

```
INSERT INTO bar
SELECT id, timestamp, updated_at
FROM foo
```

I get an error:

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "bar_pkey"
> DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.

How is this error possible when the table `bar` is compltely empty?  What is the correct procedure in postgres to perform a data copy from one table without a primary key to a table with one?

Comment: Presumably `foo` has duplicates. do you have different row counts if you `select id` and `select distinct id`

Comment: no there are no duplicates in `foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validate that `bar` is really empty:

```
select count(*)
from bar;
```

If that is not the problem, then `foo` has duplicates:

```
select id
from foo
group by id
having count(*) > 1;
```

There are other arcane possibilities such as misnamed constraints (so the issue isn't really `id`) or triggers.  However, I am discounting those possibilities.

If you want one arbitrary row per foo, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (id) id, timestamp, updated_at
from foo
order by id;
```